# How to check if a process belong to the active user session, from a exe that is running at session 0?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm running an exe as a service that launches another exe (im gonna call it `foo.exe`) as soon the current user logged in.

However when there's more than one user and I switch between them, how I could verify if any currently running `foo.exe` belongs to the new switched user, `and if don't`, then launch a `new foo.exe`?

The problem I'm facing: `process_session_id` is being returned 'wrong'.

If `i run foo.exe on the user at session 1`, and switch to `another` user in a new session'2', and call the API:

```
ProcessIdToSessionId(pid, &process_session_id);
```

with the `pid` of `foo.exe` that's running on `session1`, `process_session_id` returns 2 instead of 1.

It should return 1, as it's running on session1 and there's no `foo.exe` running on session2.

When I go to the task manager > Details and check under the tab `Session` it does display the value correctly, `session 1`.

The code below represents the exe running as service, and `it's running at the session 0`.

```
#include <wtsapi32.h>                  // For GetCurrentUserSessionId_RemoteDesktop
#pragma comment(lib, "wtsapi32.lib")   //



auto _GetAllProcessId(LPCTSTR ProcessName)
{
    std::vector<int> processes_id {};

    PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
    HANDLE hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (Process32First(hsnap, &pt)) { // must call this first
        do 
        {
            if (!lstrcmpi(pt.szExeFile, ProcessName))
                processes_id.push_back(pt.th32ProcessID);
        } while (Process32Next(hsnap, &pt));
    }
    CloseHandle(hsnap); // close handle on failure

    return processes_id;
}



DWORD GetCurrentUserSessionId_RemoteDesktop()
{
    int dwSessionId = 0;

    PWTS_SESSION_INFO pSessionInfo = 0;
    DWORD dwCount = 0;

    // Get the list of all terminal sessions 
    WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1,
        &pSessionInfo, &dwCount);

    // look over obtained list in search of the active session
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwCount; ++i)
    {
        WTS_SESSION_INFO si = pSessionInfo[i];
        if (WTSActive == si.State)
        {
            // If the current session is active – store its ID
            dwSessionId = si.SessionId;
            break;
        }
    }

    WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);

    return dwSessionId;
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    DWORD pid = 0;
    DWORD current_user_session_id = 0;
    bool process_running = false;

    std::vector<int> processes_id{};

    while (true)
    {
        processes_id = _GetAllProcessId(L"foo.exe");

        if (processes_id.empty())
        {
            // Launch the process as the current user.
            continue;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < processes_id.size(); i++)
        {
            pid = processes_id[i];

            DWORD process_session_id = 0;
            // Get the sessionId from where the given pid is running.
            ProcessIdToSessionId(pid, &process_session_id);

            // If its running on sessionId 0 we must close it.
            // As inside of this session it will not work properly.
            if (process_session_id == 0)
            {
                const auto explorer = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, pid);
                TerminateProcess(explorer, 1);
                CloseHandle(explorer);
                continue;
            }
            else
            // Check if the exe belong to the actual user logged-in.
            {
                current_user_session_id = GetCurrentUserSessionId_RemoteDesktop();

                if (process_session_id = current_user_session_id)
                    process_running = true;
            }

        }
        
        // As we could not find the process running for the current user, launch it.
        if (!process_running)
            // Launch the process as the current user.


        Sleep(10);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

To launch `foo.exe` as the current user, im using this lib: https://github.com/noelmartinon/ExecAs

Why im doing this all? `foo.exe` dont work properly when executed inside of session 0, and im trying to start him at login time.

Comment: This sounds like what you *really* want is to establish a communication channel between your service and a program launched into a user session. A solution to that problem does not require passing around process ID's or identifying the user session a process with a particular ID runs in. All you need is to set up some [IPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications).

Comment: You are not checking the return value of ProcessIdToSessionId!

Comment: `ProcessIdToSessionId()` dos not lie *if it is successful*, which you are not checking for. But also, you have a race condition. Think of what would happen if you get the process ID for `foo.exe`, and then that process exits before you call `ProcessIdToSessionId()`.  The process ID could be reused by a new process in a different session.  I agree with IInspectable.  I would have `foo.exe` create a named pipe, using its current session ID as part of the pipe name, and then have the service connect to the pipe for the desired session ID...

Comment: ... if that is not an option, then I would simply have the service run `foo.exe` unconditionally in the target session, and then have the startup code in `foo.exe` look for an existing `foo.exe` process in its current session (which could easily be handled by creating a named mutex via `CreateMutex()` using a session-local name, and then checking if the mutex already exists) and if found then just exit itself immediately, otherwise do its normal work.